# DB Query to get the correspondent next available variants from specific product page

Tags: php, mysql

I some help to build a query to get the product with correspondent variants and variant_options. I want to know which is the next available variants from specific product page.

I did an image for more information.

Actually i need the logic to know which Red option is available in Green page.
[image]

I have the following query but i think my logic is not correct for multiple variants and also i can't parse the result to build product page.

```
SELECT products.id,
       products.parent_id,
       name,
       attribute_name,
       attribute_values.value,
       if(products.id=4, 'TRUE', '') AS selected,
       #attribute_value_id AS attr_value_id,
       #if (INSTR(
                    (SELECT group_concat(attribute_value_id)
                     FROM product_variant_options
                     WHERE product_variant_options.product_id=4),attribute_value_id)>0, 'YES', '') AS y,
       if(if(INSTR(
                     (SELECT group_concat(attribute_value_id)
                      FROM product_variant_options
                      WHERE product_variant_options.product_id=4),attribute_value_id)>0, 'YES', '')='yes', products.id, '') AS id_to_open #
  (SELECT group_concat(attribute_value_id)
   FROM product_variant_options
   WHERE product_variant_options.product_id=1) x
FROM products
INNER JOIN product_variant_options ON product_variant_options.product_id=products.id
INNER JOIN product_variants ON product_variants.id=product_variant_options.product_variant_id
INNER JOIN attributes ON attributes.id=product_variants.attribute_id
INNER JOIN attribute_values ON attribute_values.id=product_variant_options.attribute_value_id
ORDER BY products.id
```

**UPDATE:**

products

```
| id | parent_id | name                           |
|----|-----------|--------------------------------|
| 1  | 0         | Phone iPhone XS, Green, 128 GB |
| 2  | 1         | Phone iPhone XS, Green, 512 GB |
| 3  | 2         | Phone iPhone XS, Red, 128 GB   |
| 4  | 3         | Phone iPhone XS, Red, 512 GB   |
```

attribute_values

```
| id | value  |
|----|--------|
| 20 | Green  |
| 21 | Red    |
| 22 | 128 GB |
| 23 | 512 GB |
```

attributes

```
| id | attribute_name |
|----|----------------|
| 10 | Color          |
| 11 | Storage        |
```

product_variants

```
| id | product_id | attribute_id |
|----|------------|--------------|
| 1  | 1          | 10           |
| 2  | 1          | 11           |
```

product_variant_options

```
| id | product_id | product_variant_id | attribute_value_id |
|----|------------|--------------------|--------------------|
| 1  | 1          |          1         |         20         |
| 2  | 1          |          2         |         22         |
| 3  | 2          |          1         |         20         |
| 4  | 2          |          2         |         23         |
| 5  | 3          |          1         |         21         |
| 6  | 3          |          2         |         22         |
| 7  | 4          |          1         |         21         |
| 8  | 4          |          2         |         23         |
```

[DB-Fiddle HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oMRHSqgJEB5ksce7A8gGPY/0)

Comment: Please, no pictures. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please check now, UPDATED